# Creation of AWS-EKS with Terraform in an existing VPC

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have created a VPC in AWS manually and I would like to create in this existing VPC an EKS via terraform.

I provide you part of the vpc.tf file:

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.2.0"

  cidr                 = "10.11.0.0/16"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = ["10.11.1.0/24", "10.11.2.0/24", "10.11.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets       = ["10.11.4.0/24", "10.11.5.0/24", "10.11.6.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  single_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    "Name" = "10.11.0.0/16 - < name of existing VPC >"  --> **if i provide here this tag EKS will be created under the existing VPC ?**
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                      = "1"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"             = "1"
  }
}
```

tags = {
"Name" = "10.11.0.0/16 - < name of existing VPC >"  --> **if i provide here this tag EKS will be created under the existing VPC ?**

is this tag will make the job ?

Comment: What problem are you asking about? What have you tried?

Comment: @Jonas i would like to create an EKS in a VPC that i have created manually.

tags = {
    "Name" = "10.11.0.0/16 - < name of existing VPC >"  --> **if i provide here this tag EKS will be created under the existing VPC ?*

Would this tag will create the EKS in the VPC that i have created manually ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the relevance of the tags here. You have created a vpc. Now when you create the [EKS Cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster), just reference these values for the [vpc_config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_cluster#vpc_config).

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  name     = "example"

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets
  }
}
```

---

Here is a good guide, [How to Provision and EKS Cluster](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks), that shows great examples of the [vpc configuration](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-provision-eks-cluster/blob/main/vpc.tf) and the [eks configuration](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-provision-eks-cluster/blob/main/eks-cluster.tf) using the provided module.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are afraid of screwing up something in an existing VPC. I would suggest that you try this in a separate account by simply create a VPC manually and then play around with your eks terraform. If you destroy the cluster and corresponding resources immediately after the provisioning, your cost should be minimal or none for testing out.

I don't think the tags you provided will put your cluster in an existing VPC. You need to configure more than that. You could potentially end up with an additional VPC.